# How many strings of length $4$ can be built from letters $a, b, c, d, e$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$B$ is a group of all strings of length $4$ built using letters $a,b,c,d,e$.

What is $|B|$?

I think the answer is $5^4$, but why we don't need to consider the duplicate letters here?

Comment: In a mathematics site, you should be careful using the word "group."  Your question has nothing whatsoever to do with groups.

Comment: $5^4$ is correct if you allow duplicate letters.  If you insist on no duplicates then it is $5\times 4\times 3\times 2$.  Usually when one speaks of "all strings", duplicates are allowed.

Comment: You should say that $B$ is *the set* of all strings of length $4$ built using letters $a, b, c, d, e$.